# Spark dataset filter elements

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, dataset

I have 2 spark datasets:
lessonDS and latestLessonDS ;

This is my spark dataset POJO:

```
Lesson class:
    private List<SessionFilter> info;
    private lessonId;

LatestLesson class:

   private String id:

SessionFilter class:
   private String id;
   private String sessionName;
```

I want to get all Lesson data where info.id in Lesson class not in LatestLesson id .

something like this:

```
lessonDS.filter(explode(col("info.id")).notEqual(latestLessonDS.col("value"))).show();

latestLessonDS contain:

100A
200C
300A
400A


lessonDS contain:

1,[[100A,jon],[200C,natalie]]
2,[[100A,jon]]
3,[[600A,jon],[400A,Kim]]

result:
3,[[600A,jon]
```

Comment: lessonDS.filter(explode(col("info.id")).notEqual(latestLessonDS.col("value"))).show();
this statement is little confusing ... if you are looking for all sessionId in left which are not there in right side  then your final result should look 3[[600A,jon]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the [array_contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#array_contains-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.Object-) function could be used as join condition when joining `lessonDs` and `latestLessonDs`. But this function does not work here as the join condition requires that *all* elements of `lessonDs.info.id` appear in `latestLessonDS`.

A way to get the result is to explode `lessonDs`, join with `latestLessonDs` and then check if for *all* elements of `lessonDs.info` an entry in `latestLessonDs` exists by comparing the number of info elements before and after the join:

```scala
lessonDs
  .withColumn("noOfEntries", size('info))
  .withColumn("id", explode(col("info.id")))
  .join(latestLessonDs, "id" )
  .groupBy("lessonId", "info", "noOfEntries").count()
  .filter("noOfEntries = count")
  .drop("noOfEntries", "count")
  .show(false)
```

prints

```
+--------+------------------------------+
|lessonId|info                          |
+--------+------------------------------+
|1       |[[100A, jon], [200C, natalie]]|
|2       |[[100A, jon]]                 |
+--------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you help me understand what
 `.groupBy("lessonId", "info", "noOfEntries").count()
              .filter("noOfEntries = count")
              .drop("noOfEntries", "count")`.  statement here means.

Why we need noOfEntries?

Comment: `count()` is the aggregation function of the `groupBy`. Here it is counted how many rows per `lessonId`are left after the join and the result is stored in a column called `count`. Then this number is compared with the number of entries before the join by comparing `count` and `noOfEntries`. Probably the easiest way to see how it works is to insert a `show` after each line and check what transformation each line does.

Comment: I just found that what I posted as result to be achieved in my question is just opposite of what I need. I have updated the result I need in question.Can you help?

Comment: Acutally this is not the exact opposite. For lesson 3 the entry for Kim is missing. For the exact opposite, you can simply change `noOfEntries = count` into `noOfEntries<>count`.

Answer (score 2):

If your dataset size latestLessonDS is reasonable enough you can collect it and broadcast
and then simple filter transformtion on lessonDS will give you desired result.

like

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
 import spark.implicits._ 
 val bc = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(latestLessonDS.collectAsList().toSeq)
    lessonDS.mapPartitions(itr => {
      val cache = bc.value;
      itr.filter(x => {
        //check in cache 
      })
    })
```

Comment: Size of latestLessonDS is close to 9GB . Can this be done using an SQL operation??

Comment: latestLessonDS.distinct size?? is 9GB is the distinct record size?

Comment: yes correct..there are no duplicates in latestLessonDS

Comment: Can this be done using an sql query, I am not sure how to achieve the result with SQL queery

Comment: @Coder123 yes you can do it ... By using (In|Exist) operator with SubQuery ... Before doing that create tempTables of dataframes with exploded info.. then do spark.sql("select * from df1 where df1.id IN (select df2.value from df2)"); to get desired result.